# Would it make sense to add logging in MVC controller OnException () if I also have logging in Application_Error()?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

In my ASP.NET MVC3 application I want all unexpected problems logged. So I have logging inside `Application_Error()`. Also I found there's `Controller.OnException()` method and so I made an override for my controllers that log the error and then call `base.OnException()`.

Looks like every time an exception occurs in a controller action my `OnException()` override is called and then `Application_Error()` is called and so logging is performed twice.

If I eliminate my `OnException()` override and only leave logging in `Application_Error()` will I still log all the problems or will I miss any kind of events?

Answer (score 0):

Controller.OnException() is MVC specific. Application_Error() is ASP.NET specific. MVC sits on top of ASP.NET, so if you handle the exception in Controller.OnException(), you may want to set ExceptionContext's ExceptionHandled to true so that it doesn't propagate down the pipeline into Application_Error().

You're right in that every error can be allowed to propagate to the Application_Error() level and handled there. It really depends on choice and preference I think. I see it both ways. I see the benefit in handling action method specific errors in Controller's OnException and other errors when the request does not even reach the controller (e.g. start-up errors, 404s) in Application_Error. When you have a hybrid app that uses both MVC and web forms, then Application_Error has to be used for web forms errors.

So while handling exceptions in Application_Error() is a must-have for making sure your app doesn't have uncaught exceptions, using Controller.OnException() is a matter of preference for handling a specific subset of errors.

Comment: The deal is I don't really "handle" those exception - I just log them and let them propagate.